# Play Video by trigger('play') for 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $('a.thumbnail').click(function(){ 
  $(this).('.cu_vd').trigger('play');
});
```

```js
 $('a.thumbnail').click(function(){ 
      $(this).('.cu_vd').trigger('play');
    });
```

I am trying to play the video by trigger but the video boxes are multiple with the same class. So I am trying to use 'this' so that It does not trigger to all, but it's not working This is the HTML page, where I am trying to play the video

https://dev-visualshowcase.cvent.com/bkeventvideos.html click on the IOV 1 (First box) the pop-up triggers and I want to play this video with JS function, instead of autoplay, because autoplay is not supporting in IOS https://dev-visualshowcase.cvent.com/eventvideos.html - here you can check the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **data-attribute** to target a specific video

```
<button class="thumbnail" data-target="video_1">Play the video</button>

<video id="video_1" playsinline="" preload="auto" muted="" controls="" loop="">
  <source src="https://dev-visualshowcase.cvent.com/VS/video/vd_intro/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Each time you click on the **.thumbnail** button, you use the **data-target** to choose your video

```
 $('.thumbnail').click(function(){ 
   let target = $(this).attr('data-target')
   $('#' + target).trigger('play');
 });
```

Comment: Hi Wmalbos, I tried Its not working,  also, I cannot change my HTML from anchor to button, because it has other functions associated, like featherlight pop-up